# Expand drop down area of asp:DropDownList

Tags: asp.net

VS 2008 - Visual Basic .NET (C# example is fine, as I can read that as well)

I have an asp:DropDownList that is 100px wide, however some of my list items are much wider than that.

How can I expand the drop down area of the list so it shows all of the text of the list items? The control itself must stay at 100px - only the drop down area can expand.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Hrm. I don't know that you can do that with ASP because of the way the browser handles dropdowns.

You could, however, create your own dropdownlist-like control with JavaScript that acts this way.

Answer (score 0):

EndangeredMassa is right.

You have no control over how the browser renders it's controls from your code. Unfortunately.